# Returning value from templated derived class using base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

If I have a base class, and a templated derived class, how can I access the stored value in the derived class using a pointer to the base class?

```cpp
class base {
public:
    virtual auto get();
};

template <typename T>
class derived : public base {
public:
    derived(T val) {m_val = val}
    ~derived(){}

    auto get(){
        return m_val;
    }
private:
    m_val;
};
```

This obviously errors out, as you can't have a virtual auto/template function.

My main motivation is to elsewhere have something like

```cpp
std::vector<base*> v;
```

and be able to access values like

```cpp
return v.at(2)->get(); // calls overridden get and returns m_val of the appropriate type
```

Currently stuck on how to get around this. I'm more interested in being able to store a vector of pointers to base and accessing things like I showed, even if it means mangling class structure.

Comment: How can you know the type of `v.at(2)->get()` if the contents of `v` isn't known at compile time? Also, depending on what you're doing, you might be able to use a `std::vector<std::any> v;` instead

Comment: Is the purpose of `base` to have a common base class (so that you can `delete` via a base class pointer)? If not, you could use CRTP and you won't need polymorphism.

Comment: @Artyer The user would call something like `get<derivedInstance>(key)` (which would in turn eventually call something like `v.at(2)->get()`), and know what type to expect (see other reply). And, thanks!

Comment: @TedLyngmo  I am really trying to store a single vector of differently typed `derived<T>` classes (which I believe can be done by storing the base pointer for each). Like, a single vector including a `class derivedA : derived<int>` object and a `class derivedB : derived<float>` object. Thanks!